# Larave BelongsTo relationship returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two Eloquent models:

**1) Project :**

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'user_id', 'account_id'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Account::class, "account_id");
    }
```

**2) Account :**

```php
class Account extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
```

The goal is to have returned the account of the project :

```
Project::with("account")->get()->pluck("account");
```

**Result :**

```
null
```

Comment: can you share your db column name?

Comment: if you want to pluck, you must pluck by column name (in this case youre pluck it with account which is model if im not wrong.) just get the ID, and you can do something with it latter

Answer (score 0):

Well each project has an account, When you do

`Project::with('account')->get()` this means you will get projects with their account and some project may have not an account yet in this case you will get a null when you try to get an account

`$projects = Project::with('account')->get();`

`$projects->first()->account` (here you are not sure about account if exists or not)

`Project::whereHas('account')->get()` this one will get only project who it has an account

this line of code you wrote, `Project::with("account")->get()->pluck("account");`

when you run it if you have multiple projects with their account and some has no account your results will be like so

```
App\Account..
App\Account..
null
null
App\Account..
```

if you like to use your code you need to filter by using collection filter then pluck the account to skip the null accounts (which is not recommended)

```
Project::with("account")
  ->get()
  ->filter(fn($project) => $project->account);
  ->pluck("account");
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you do something like :

```
$projects = Project::all();

$projects->each(function($project) {
  echo $project->account
})
```

Comment: Hi @François Auclair, thanks for your answer. actually, it can be but is there a way to do it using **with**

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use this? There is no any condition on your query, so get all accounts directly

```
Account::all();
```

If you have condition you can use this;

```
Account::whereHas('projects', function($query){
    $query->where('user_id', 1); //projects' user_id
})->get();
```

Comment: Hi @alprnkeskekoglu, thank you for your answer. In fact, i'm currently making a custom filter by project ( based on the project model ) in this case it won't solve the problem.